# Unable to do Operation on child of listView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want to get the child of listview and set the visibility of its two hidden element to true.
My code is

```
canvasListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                /*
                joinCanvasBtn.setEnabled(true);
                joinCanvasPasswordTxt.setEnabled(true);*/
                Log.d(TAG,"Selected positon : "+position);
                int index = canvasListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() + position;
                View v = canvasListView.getChildAt(index);
                if(v!=null) {
                    joinCanvasBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.joinCanvasBtn);
                    canvasPassword = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.joinCanvasPasswordTxt);

                    joinCanvasBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    joinCanvasPasswordTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                else {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Unable to find the selected child of listView");
                }


            }
        });
```

But this is not working its giving me Nullpointer exception. My layout file is given below. Basically I want to show the password and join button whenever user click on that row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"

    android:padding="6dip">
    <!-- Item Name -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/canvasName"
        android:height="100dp"
         />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/canvasCreator"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/joinCanvasPasswordTxt"
           android:visibility="invisible"
        />   
     <Button
         android:id="@+id/joinCanvasBtn"
         android:text="Join"
         android:visibility="invisible" 
         />


</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me to find the solution

Comment: if(index>=0){ .. setVisibility true code...)}else{Log.d(TAG,"please select");} could help

Comment: that wont help i tried it

Answer (score 0):

Try to write

```
int index = position - canvasListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

instead of

```
int index = canvasListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() + position;
```